# Tetrahedron on the surface of a 4-dimensional sphere

Tags: geometry

I think it is well known that the sum of the angles of a triangle on the surface of 3-dimensional sphere may exceed 180° .

However I wondered now, if it were possible to generalize this for example by putting a tetrahedron onto the surface of a 4-dimension sphere.

As far I know the maximum sum of all angles in a symmetric tetrahedron, euclidean space is: $ \arccos { 1\over 3} \cong 70.528779^° $

Is it possible to exceed the sum?

Comment: There is an analogous theorem for tetrahedrons, namely that $\sum_{i=1}^4 \Omega_i - 2\sum_{i=1}^6 \phi_i + 4\pi = 0$, where $\Omega_i$ are the four solid angles of a tetrahedron at its vertices and $\phi_i$ are the 6 dihedral angles at its edges (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Tetrahedron) ). That theorem is what fails in non-Euclidean geometries.

Comment: I am not even sure, if the terminus angle can be generalized well to non planar spaces. Perhaps it were better to ask for the maximum Volume of the object lying on top of the surface given its perimeter.